# Time Complexity of logn.logn

Tags: time-complexity, code-complexity

I'm trying to find the complexity of the following code, what I think is the upper part works logn time, and bottom part as well as a result, which ends up with logn square, and that is practically logn. But can't be sure as there is an inner loop so it doesn't feel okay to equalize it to the complexity without inner loop.

code:

```
for (i = 1; i < N; i *= 2) {
    for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        sum += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a complexity question @sanyash

Comment: Also, the outer loop starts with 0, so essentially, you will always run for `i = 0`.

Comment: the complexity is `O(1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + n/2 + n)` which is the sum of geometric series with factor=2

Comment: @sanyash this is not my code or anyone's code that is used anywhere. this is a mind exercise to find the complexity of the given code, we don't need to optimize it

Comment: @mangusta `O(GeometricSum * log(N)` ?

Comment: @user007 good point, fixed question for that

Comment: @user007 `O(GeometricSum)`

Comment: TLDR O(n). `O(1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + n/2 + n)` gives `n * 2 - 1` if n is a power of two.

Comment: @mangusta Right! Sorry!!